# 1С не выгружается большой каталог товаров на сайт

Tags: 1с

Нужно выгрузить большой каталог товаров на сайт с 1С Предприятия. Делаю это через узел обмена с сайтом. Когда я выбираю выгрузить все товары (их порядка 3 тысяч), обмен с сайтом не происходит.

Когда выгружаю по одной рубрике, выгруз товаров происходит, но все равно не всех рубрик.

С чем это может быть связано? Может у хостинг провайдера установлены какие-то ограничения?

Comment: > обмен с сайтом не происходит - При этом выдаётся какая-нибудь ошибка?

Comment: У хостинг-провайдера наверняка установлены ограничения. Например, вы превышаете время выполнения скрипта или скрипт потребляет слишком много памяти.

Comment: @MikhailSibirev не происходит. Ошибки никакой нет.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman стоят следующие ограничения: http://prntscr.com/eso7e4

Comment: Могу только посоветовать открыть конфигуратор и в режиме отладки смотреть, что на самом деле происходит.